# Existe alguma razão pela separação dos pacotes java e javax?

Tags: java

Na [documentação do java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/overview-summary.html#overview.description), há vários pacotes organizados dentro do pacote *java* e *javax*, em sua grande maioria. Há até alguns pacotes que parecem ser duplicados, como `java.sql` e `javax.sql`. Há alguma explicação para essa separação?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A separação entre esses pacotes é para uma melhor organização.
O pacote java é mais básico e o pacote `javax` são funcionalidades extras, aprimoradas, que podem fazer uso de classes do java puro ou não.

As classes do pacote `java` são mais antigas, já as classes do `javax` são extensões. Repare que no caso do sql, se for analisar o *javadoc* de uma classe `javax`, ela deve conter também o *import* para as classes do java básico que está tomando, para acrescentar funcionalidades extras. Já vendo o javadoc de uma classe do pacote java puro, não encontrará imports de classes do pacote javax.

Resumindo, javax complementa as classes do java puro.

Comment: Antonio, removi o trecho final para que o conteudo de sua resposta fique objetivo, focando apenas em responder a questão.

Answer (score 4):

Seguindo a linha de Raciocinio do Stack Ingles  disponivel aqui:

[javax vs java package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727844/javax-vs-java-package)

**Historicamente falando:**

Originalmente Extensões Do java em uma JRE pré existente eram colocados como ***javax***, ou seja originalmente o pacote javax é feito apenas para extensões do pacote java

Um dos motivos para tal era o **NETSCAPE**, o mesmo limitava alguns pacotes que estavam disponiveis no **PACOTE JAVA**

Hoje, para a comunidade ao menos, o ponto javax/java foi perdido, pois hoje tudo que existe no javax praticamente ja existe no java.

Nota:
Trechos das respostas do stack ingles do link disponibilizado

Comment: vou traduzir e colocar então para Facilitar